# How can I install 'emopt' library in python

Tags: python, conda

I'm trying to install `emopt` library, but this error occurs.

Could you let me know how to fix this errors and how to install `emopt` ?

Thanks.

### error code

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>pip install emopt

Collecting emopt
  Using cached emopt-0.2.3.1.tar.gz (51 kB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done
Building wheels for collected packages: emopt
  Building wheel for emopt (setup.py) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × python setup.py bdist_wheel did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [20 lines of output]
      running bdist_wheel
      running build
      running build_py
      creating build
      creating build\lib
      creating build\lib\emopt
      copying emopt\adjoint_method.py -> build\lib\emopt
      copying emopt\fdfd.py -> build\lib\emopt
      copying emopt\fomutils.py -> build\lib\emopt
      copying emopt\grid.py -> build\lib\emopt
      copying emopt\misc.py -> build\lib\emopt
      copying emopt\modedata.py -> build\lib\emopt
      copying emopt\modes.py -> build\lib\emopt
      copying emopt\optimizer.py -> build\lib\emopt
      copying emopt\__init__.py -> build\lib\emopt
      creating build\lib\emopt\data
      copying emopt\data\silicon.csv -> build\lib\emopt\data
      installing to build\bdist.win-amd64\wheel
      running install
      error: [WinError 2] 지정된 파일을 찾을 수 없습니다
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for emopt
  Running setup.py clean for emopt
Failed to build emopt
Installing collected packages: emopt
  Running setup.py install for emopt ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × Running setup.py install for emopt did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [2 lines of output]
      running install
      error: [WinError 2] 지정된 파일을 찾을 수 없습니다
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: legacy-install-failure

× Encountered error while trying to install package.
╰─> emopt

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for output from the failure.
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the installation instructions provided [here](https://emopt.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html)?
It seems that other dependencies are installed via local package management tools like apt or pip, while EMopt is installed by cloning the repository and install it with the install.py script inside the repo.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I've tried that installation instruction, but in that link, there is no instructions for 'Windows OS '. I use 'Windows 10'. Is that means that I cannot install 'emopt' in Windows OS ?